# Getting table cell elements from a button click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

Assuming I have a table like below:
[image]

The table is generated using PHP. The update button should launch one of two interfaces depending on the Report type. The problem I have is getting each Update button to correspond to the Report type in its particular row only. I have tried this with the following code :

```
<table id="reportTbl" border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Report</th>
    <th>Data</th>       
    <th>Update</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Encrypted</td>
    <td>Image</td>      
     <td><input type="submit" class="tbl_Update" value="Update" onclick="runPop();"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Unencrypted</td>
    <td>Document</td>       
    <td><input type="submit" class="tbl_Update" value="Update" onclick="runPop();"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

     function runPop() {
         var pop = new myPop();
         var cells = document.getElementById('reportTbl').getElementsByTagName('td');
         for (i = 0; i < cells.length;) {
             var report = document.getElementById('reportTbl').getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
             pop.popOut(report);
             console.log(report);
             i += 3;
         }
     }
```

`myPopout()` represents the class which handles the two interfaces it does this by checking the Report type.

The problem with the code above is when I click the button both interfaces are opened one on top of each other which must be due to the loop. How would I fix this?

Comment: Can you update the HTML that is generated by chance? (To include a `data-*` attribute)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the clicked button reference to `runPop` then use that to get the reference to the `tr` element and using that you can you can get the first tr

```
<td><input type="submit" class="tbl_Update" value="Update" onclick="runPop(this);"></td>
```

then

```
function runPop(el) {
    var report = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
    var pop = new myPop();
    pop.popOut(report);
    console.log(report);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time and examples.

Answer (score 3):

You should not put javascript in your HTML, and you should use delegate events:

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell #1 Row #1</td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="tbl_Update" value="Update" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell #1 Row #2</td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="tbl_Update" value="Update" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
myTable.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var button = e.target;
    var cell = button.parentNode;
    var row = cell.parentNode;
    var rowFirstCellText = row.querySelector('td').innerHTML;
    console.log(button);
    console.log(cell);
    console.log(row);
    console.log(rowFirstCellText);
}, false);
```

Live example here : http://jsfiddle.net/ueg19uv4/

Comment: Why is it bad practice to have Javascript in HTML?

Comment: Well, first, because doing so you entangle Structure and Behaviour. Do you place CSS in your HTML as well? It is good practice in any language/technology/framework to separate concerns (Here, you should separate Structure in HTML, Appearance in CSS, and Behaviour in JavaScript).You should read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Besides, you should avoid creating so much listeners (one per button, in your code), when you can have the same result with only one (in my code).