# Add a row in Google Sheet using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner in google app script. I am creating resident payment system where if the user increases the number of paid by one I want to add the a new row in sales worksheet in google sheet with new invoice number and the address of the specific user (which means lets say the user's address is 16, Jalan Sanggul 4 so I want to add it to the worksheet under the address column). I have attached few images and link to my google appscript coding here to explain myself better. I really hope that you guys can help me with it. Thank you guys.

Link to google app script (There is few numbers of html there so give the link ) - https://script.google.com/d/1NvaCQBc1fZWT7Y5cdvSi_XVL2-ytRVDP41AgY-btOA_MYrd8vcQK4fb_/edit?usp=sharing

Link to google sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GO_kQVuXBtBZSKreNSvYu_kTRQMuL7YN5VXd14zgMig/edit?usp=sharing

[[Payment Data Image (1) - Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Tp5.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Tp5.jpg)

[[Payment Data Image (2)- Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuxP6.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuxP6.jpg)

[image][image]

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
  .setTitle("Admin Login")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


//Check Login
function checkLogin(loginUsername, loginPassword) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=1151242353';
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Admin Data");
  var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
  var found_record = '';
  for(var i = 1; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
   if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == loginUsername && 
     webAppSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() == loginPassword)
   {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
   }    
  }
  if(found_record == '')
  {
    found_record = 'FALSE'; 
  }
  
  return found_record;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------GLOBAL VARIABLES---------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function globalVariables(){ 
  var varArray = {
    spreadsheetId        : '1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8', //** CHANGE !!!
    admindataRage        : 'Admin Data!A2:B',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    adminidRange         : 'Admin Data!A2:A',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    adminlastCol         : 'B',                                            //** CHANGE !!!
    admininsertRange     : 'Admin Data!A1:B1',                                   //** CHANGE !!!
    adminsheetID         : '1151242353',
    dataRage             : 'USERNAMES!A2:H',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    idRange              : 'USERNAMES!A2:A',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    lastCol              : 'H',                                            //** CHANGE !!!
    insertRange          : 'USERNAMES!A1:H1',                                   //** CHANGE !!!
    sheetID              : '0'
  };
  return varArray;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------FUCNTION FOR ADMIN CRUD PART-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/* PROCESS FORM */
function processAdminForm(formObject){  
  if(formObject.admin_uname && checkAdminID(formObject.admin_uname)){//Execute if form passes an ID and if is an existing ID
    updateAdminData(getAdminFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,getAdminRangeByID(formObject.admin_uname)); // Update Data
  }else{ //Execute if form does not pass an ID
    appendAdminData(getAdminFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().admininsertRange); //Append Form Data
  }
  return getAdminLastTenRows();//Return last 10 rows
}


/* GET FORM VALUES AS AN ARRAY */
function getAdminFormValues(formObject){
/* ADD OR REMOVE VARIABLES ACCORDING TO YOUR FORM*/
  if(formObject.admin_uname && checkAdminID(formObject.admin_uname)){
    var values = [[
                  //formObject.username.toString(),
                  formObject.admin_uname,
                  formObject.admin_pw]];
  }else{
    var values = [[
                  //new Date().getTime().toString(),//https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51012/244121
                  formObject.admin_uname,
                  formObject.admin_pw]];

  }
  return values;
}



/* CREATE/ APPEND DATA */
function appendAdminData(values, spreadsheetId,range){
  var valueRange = Sheets.newRowData();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var appendRequest = Sheets.newAppendCellsRequest();
  appendRequest.adminsheetID = spreadsheetId;
  appendRequest.rows = valueRange;
  var results = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range,{valueInputOption: "RAW"});
}


/* READ DATA */
function readAdminData(spreadsheetId,range){
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
  return result.values;
}


/* UPDATE DATA */
function updateAdminData(values,spreadsheetId,range){
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, {
  valueInputOption: "RAW"});
}


/*DELETE DATA*/
function deleteAdminData(ID){ 
  //https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate
  //https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns
  var startIndex = getAdminRowIndexByID(ID);
  
  var deleteRange = {
                      "sheetId"     : globalVariables().adminsheetID,
                      "dimension"   : "ROWS",
                      "startIndex"  : startIndex,
                      "endIndex"    : startIndex+1
                    }
  
  var deleteRequest= [{"deleteDimension":{"range":deleteRange}}];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests": deleteRequest}, globalVariables().spreadsheetId);
  
  return getAdminLastTenRows();//Return last 10 rows
}



/* CHECK FOR EXISTING ID, RETURN BOOLEAN */
function checkAdminID(ID){
  var idList = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().adminidRange,).reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b);});
  return idList.includes(ID);
}


/* GET DATA RANGE A1 NOTATION FOR GIVEN ID */
function getAdminRangeByID(id){
  if(id){
    var idList = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().adminidRange);
    for(var i=0;i<idList.length;i++){
      if(id==idList[i][0]){
        return 'Admin Data!A'+(i+2)+':'+globalVariables().adminlastCol+(i+2);
      }
    }
  }
}


/* GET RECORD BY ID */
function getAdminRecordById(id){
  if(id && checkAdminID(id)){
    var result = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,getAdminRangeByID(id));
    return result;
  }
}


/* GET ROW NUMBER FOR GIVEN ID */
function getAdminRowIndexByID(id){
  if(id){
    var idList = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().adminidRange);
    for(var i=0;i<idList.length;i++){
      if(id==idList[i][0]){
        var rowIndex = parseInt(i+1);
        return rowIndex;
      }
    }
  }
}


/*GET LAST 10 RECORDS */
function getAdminLastTenRows(){
  var lastRow = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().admindataRage).length+1;
  if(lastRow<=11){
    var range = globalVariables().admindataRage;
  }else{
    var range = 'Admin Data!A'+(lastRow-9)+':'+globalVariables().adminlastCol;
  }
  var lastTenRows = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,range);
  return lastTenRows;
}


/* GET ALL RECORDS */
function getAdminAllData(){
  var data = readAdminData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().admindataRage);
  return data;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------FUCNTION FOR RESIDENT CRUD PART-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  if(formObject.username && checkID(formObject.username)){//Execute if form passes an ID and if is an existing ID
    updateData(getFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,getRangeByID(formObject.username)); // Update Data
  }else{ //Execute if form does not pass an ID
    appendData(getFormValues(formObject),globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().insertRange); //Append Form Data
  }
  return getLastTenRows();//Return last 10 rows
}


/* GET FORM VALUES AS AN ARRAY */
function getFormValues(formObject){
/* ADD OR REMOVE VARIABLES ACCORDING TO YOUR FORM*/
  if(formObject.username && checkID(formObject.username)){
    var values = [[
                  //formObject.username.toString(),
                  formObject.username,
                  formObject.housenumber,
                  formObject.street,
                  formObject.firstname,
                  formObject.lastname,
                  formObject.noOfPaid,
                  formObject.password,
                  formObject.phone]];
  }else{
    var values = [[
                  //new Date().getTime().toString(),//https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51012/244121
                  formObject.username,
                  formObject.housenumber,
                  formObject.street,
                  formObject.firstname,
                  formObject.lastname,
                  formObject.noOfPaid,
                  formObject.password,
                  formObject.phone]];

  }
  return values;
}


/* CREATE/ APPEND DATA */
function appendData(values, spreadsheetId,range){
  var valueRange = Sheets.newRowData();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var appendRequest = Sheets.newAppendCellsRequest();
  appendRequest.sheetID = spreadsheetId;
  appendRequest.rows = valueRange;
  var results = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range,{valueInputOption: "RAW"});
}


/* READ DATA */
function readData(spreadsheetId,range){
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
  return result.values;
}


/* UPDATE DATA */
function updateData(values,spreadsheetId,range){
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, {
  valueInputOption: "RAW"});
}


/*DELETE DATA*/
function deleteData(ID){ 
  //https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate
  //https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns
  var startIndex = getRowIndexByID(ID);
  
  var deleteRange = {
                      "sheetId"     : globalVariables().sheetID,
                      "dimension"   : "ROWS",
                      "startIndex"  : startIndex,
                      "endIndex"    : startIndex+1
                    }
  
  var deleteRequest= [{"deleteDimension":{"range":deleteRange}}];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests": deleteRequest}, globalVariables().spreadsheetId);
  
  return getLastTenRows();//Return last 10 rows
}


/* CHECK FOR EXISTING ID, RETURN BOOLEAN */
function checkID(ID){
  var idList = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().idRange,).reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b);});
  return idList.includes(ID);
}


/* GET DATA RANGE A1 NOTATION FOR GIVEN ID */
function getRangeByID(id){
  if(id){
    var idList = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().idRange);
    for(var i=0;i<idList.length;i++){
      if(id==idList[i][0]){
        return 'USERNAMES!A'+(i+2)+':'+globalVariables().lastCol+(i+2);
      }
    }
  }
}


/* GET RECORD BY ID */
function getRecordById(id){
  if(id && checkID(id)){
    var result = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,getRangeByID(id));
    return result;
  }
}


/* GET ROW NUMBER FOR GIVEN ID */
function getRowIndexByID(id){
  if(id){
    var idList = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().idRange);
    for(var i=0;i<idList.length;i++){
      if(id==idList[i][0]){
        var rowIndex = parseInt(i+1);
        return rowIndex;
      }
    }
  }
}


/*GET LAST 10 RECORDS */
function getLastTenRows(){
  var lastRow = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().dataRage).length+1;
  if(lastRow<=11){
    var range = globalVariables().dataRage;
  }else{
    var range = 'USERNAMES!A'+(lastRow-9)+':'+globalVariables().lastCol;
  }
  var lastTenRows = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,range);
  return lastTenRows;
}


/* GET ALL RECORDS */
function getAllData(){
  var data = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().dataRage);
  return data;
}


/*GET DROPDOWN LIST */
function getDropdownList(range){
  var list = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,range);
  return list;
}


//CODE FOR DATA SEARCH
function searchData(formObject){  
  var result = [];
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(globalVariables().spreadsheetId, globalVariables().dataRage).values;
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
          if(data[i][j].toLowerCase().search(formObject.searchtext.toLowerCase())!=-1){
            result.push(data[i])
          }
        }
      }
  }
  return result;
}

/* INCLUDE HTML PARTS, EG. JAVASCRIPT, CSS, OTHER HTML FILES */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getScriptURL() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url ;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        -->
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
        <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?> <!-- See JavaScript.html file -->
        <?!= include('CSS'); ?> <!-- See CSS.html file -->
    </head>
    
    <body onload="createStreetDropdown()">
      <div id="loginDisplay" class="loginDisplay">
        <?!= include('loginDisplay'); ?>
      </div>

    
      <div style="display:none"  id="dataDisplay"  >
      
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="LogOut()">
            Log out
          </button>
          <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" onclick="LogOut()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log out
          </button>-->
        </div>
        
        <br>
        
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">
            Admin
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">
            Resident
          </button>
        </div>
      
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <?!= include('AdminForm'); ?> 
                  <br><br>
                  <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <?!= include('AdminDataTable'); ?> 
                </div>
                <!--
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <?!= include('AdminDataTable'); ?> 
                </div>
                -->
            </div>    
            <br><br>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <?!= include('Form'); ?> 
                  <br><br>
                  <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <?!= include('DataTable'); ?> 
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>

//--------Login Page----------------------------------

function LoginUser()
    {
    var loginUsername = document.getElementById("loginUsername").value;
    var loginPassword = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value;
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
    {
      if(output == 'TRUE')
      {
        document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";     
      }
      else if(output == 'FALSE')
      {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Failed to Login";     
      }    
    }).checkLogin(loginUsername, loginPassword);
    }
    
//-------Log Out----------------------   
    function LogOut(){  
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(url){window.open(url,"_top");})
      .getScriptURL();
      //var url=window.location.href
      //window.open(url,'_top');
      //window.open("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyS5LJn4i6mJeMzjWWryW7TUUDeeAZtVteJdCd6lT0FPPEiCiVy/exec",'_top');
    }
    
    
//----------------------------------------------------------
//---------Admin Part---------------------------------------

  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventAdminFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", adminfunctionInit, true); 
  
  //INITIALIZE FUNCTIONS ONLOAD
  function adminfunctionInit(){  
    preventAdminFormSubmit();
    getAdminLastTenRows();
  };      
  
  //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
  function handleAdminFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createAdminTable).processAdminForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("adminForm").reset();
  }
  
  //GET LAST 10 ROWS
  function getAdminLastTenRows (){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createAdminTable).getAdminLastTenRows();
  }
  
  
  //GET ALL DATA
  function getAdminAllData(){
    //document.getElementById('adminDataTable').innerHTML = "";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createAdminTable).getAdminAllData();
  }
  
  
  //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
  function createAdminTable(dataArray) {
    if(dataArray){
      var result = "<table class='table table-sm' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                   "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                     "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                      "<th scope='col'>Delete</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Edit</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Username</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Password</th>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                  "</thead>";
      for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
          result += "<tr>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteBtn' onclick='deleteAdminData(this);'>Delete</button></td>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs editBtn' onclick='editAdminData(this);'>Edit</button></td>";
          for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
              result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
          }
          result += "</tr>";
      }
      result += "</table>";
      var div = document.getElementById('adminDataTable');
      div.innerHTML = result;
      document.getElementById("admin_message").innerHTML = "";
    }else{
      var div = document.getElementById('adminDataTable');
      div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
    }
  }

  //DELETE DATA
  function deleteAdminData(el) {
    var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
    if (result) {
      var admin_uname = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createAdminTable).deleteAdminData(admin_uname);
    }
  }
  
  //EDIT DATA
  function editAdminData(el){
    var admin_uname = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML; //https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377357/2391195
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateAdminForm).getAdminRecordById(admin_uname);
  }

  //POPULATE FORM
  function populateAdminForm(records){
    document.getElementById('admin_uname').value = records[0][0];
    document.getElementById('admin_pw').value = records[0][1];  
    document.getElementById("admin_message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>Update Record [ADMIN: "+records[0][0]+"]</div>";
  }
  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------Resident Part------------------------------------------
 
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", functionInit, true); 
  
  //INITIALIZE FUNCTIONS ONLOAD
  function functionInit(){  
    preventFormSubmit();
    getLastTenRows();
  };      
  
  //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  
  //GET LAST 10 ROWS
  function getLastTenRows (){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getLastTenRows();
  }
  
  
  //GET ALL DATA
  function getAllData(){
    //document.getElementById('dataTable').innerHTML = "";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getAllData();
  }
  
  
  //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
  function createTable(dataArray) {
    if(dataArray){
      var result = "<table class='table table-sm' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                   "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                     "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                      "<th scope='col'>Delete</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Edit</th>"+
                      //"<th scope='col'>ID</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Username</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>House Number</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Street</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>First Name</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Last Name</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>No of Paid</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Password</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Phone</th>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                  "</thead>";
      for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
          result += "<tr>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteBtn' onclick='deleteData(this);'>Delete</button></td>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs editBtn' onclick='editData(this);'>Edit</button></td>";
          for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
              result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
          }
          result += "</tr>";
      }
      result += "</table>";
      var div = document.getElementById('dataTable');
      div.innerHTML = result;
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
    }else{
      var div = document.getElementById('dataTable');
      div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
    }
  }

  //DELETE DATA
  function deleteData(el) {
    var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
    if (result) {
      var username = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).deleteData(username);
    }
  }
  
  
  //EDIT DATA
  function editData(el){
    var username = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML; //https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377357/2391195
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateForm).getRecordById(username);
  }

  //POPULATE FORM
  function populateForm(records){
    document.getElementById('username').value = records[0][0];
    document.getElementById('housenumber').value = records[0][1];
    document.getElementById('street').value = records[0][2];
    document.getElementById('firstname').value = records[0][3];
    document.getElementById('lastname').value = records[0][4];
    document.getElementById('noOfPaid').value = records[0][5];
    document.getElementById('password').value = records[0][6];
    document.getElementById('phone').value = records[0][7];    
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>Update Record [ID: "+records[0][0]+"]</div>";
  }
  
  //RETRIVE DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET FOR STREET DROPDOWN
  function createStreetDropdown() {
      //SUBMIT YOUR DATA RANGE FOR DROPDOWN AS THE PARAMETER
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(streetDropDown).getDropdownList("Configuration!A2:A11");
  }
  
  //POPULATE STREET DROPDOWNS
  function streetDropDown(values) { //Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391195
    var list = document.getElementById('street');   
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = values[i];
      option.text = values[i];
      list.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
  
  //SEARCH DATA
  function handleSearchForm(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).searchData(formObject);
    document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
  }
  
</script>
```

**AdminForm.html**

```
<form id="adminForm" class="p-2 border border-light rounded bg-light" onsubmit="handleAdminFormSubmit(this)"> 
    <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Admin Form</p>
    
    <div id="admin_message"></div>
    <input type="text" id="admin_message" name="admin_message" value="" style="display: none">
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="admin_uname" >Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="admin_uname" name="admin_uname" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="admin_pw" >Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="admin_pw" name="admin_pw" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Please consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for replying bro. So basically bro, what I am trying to do is if a user have increased the number of paid by one, I want a script where it automatically add to last row of my google sheet with their particular address and a new invoice number. I provide you the link to my web app bro. The **Username : Mathavan Password : Apple** . You would understand clearly with that web app bro. I really want your help in this project bro. Hope you would lend me a hand in this.

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzkGzHWowHQCPutZh5bkXS2mUPCaS5NkyEs5WjbOhcF1zscUv71Zn8K_b8iyyspabCD/exec

Comment: @Iamblichus Bro if you received the comment would you mind reply me because I dont know whether the comment is showing or what. Sorry for disturbing you bro

Comment: Yes your comment is visible. I cannot take a look at this at the moment though.

Comment: @Iamblichus Owh okay then bro. If you can make it, I really hope that you will help me out to sort out this problem. Thank you so much bro

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: @MetaMan Bro I have added the coding here

Comment: Did you solve the login issue?

Comment: Where's Adminform?.....

Comment: @MetaMan Yeah bro I did managed to solve it with your help. Thanks for being there with me

Comment: @MetaMan Bro so so sorry. I had some problem with my connection. Vert much sorry bro. I will update it now sorry bro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232672/discussion-between-lee-wei-liang-and-metaman).