# how to fix datatable responsive bootstrap 5 delete button not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a datatable responsive bootstrap 5 delete & Edit button working very good befor expended the row or click + on the table,
[like this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWI0c.png), after i click + and expended the table on mobile screen not workin like this pic [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEh9W.png). I'm not programmer and trying to do my page by Google Script, thux in advance

the code:

```
* Prevent forms from submitting.
   * */

  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", functionInit, true); 
  
  /**
   * INITIALIZE FUNCTIONS ONLOAD
   * */

  function functionInit(){  
    preventFormSubmit();
    getLastTenRows();
  };  

  /**
   * HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
   * */

  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
   // setTimeout(function() {$('#myModal').modal('hide');}, 10000);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>Added the record successfully.</div>";
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }

 /**
   * Clear form when pop-up is closed.  
   * */

  function clearForm() {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getAllData();
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner5').classList.remove("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner6').classList.remove("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner7').classList.remove("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner8').classList.remove("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner9').classList.remove("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner10').classList.remove("d-none");

  function createTable(dataArray) {
      $('#btn-close').click()
      $(document).ready(function(){
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner5').classList.add("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner6').classList.add("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner7').classList.add("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner8').classList.add("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner9').classList.add("d-none");
      document.getElementById('resp-spinner10').classList.add("d-none");  
      $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    //data: dataArray,
      data: dataArray.slice(1),
     columns: [
      { title: "ID" },
      { title: "Name" },
      { title: "State" }, 
      { title: "Date" }, 
      { title: "Mobile No" },
      { title: "Address" },
      { title: "Remarks" },
 { title: "Edit", "render": function (data,type, row, meta){
              return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-warning btn-xs editBtn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' onclick='editData(this);'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>";
            }
        },

 { title: "Delete", "render": function (data,type){
              return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs deleteBtn' onclick='deleteData(this);'><i class='fa fa-trash''></i></button>";
            }
        },
     ],
  "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
          nRow.setAttribute('id',aData[0]);
          },

    
    // "ordering": false,
       destroy:true, 
       responsive:true,     
       lengthMenu: [
          [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],
          ['5', '10', '25', '50','100', 'All' ]
      ],
      
      order: [[2, "asc"], [2, "asc"], ],
      });
    });
  }
  /**
   * DELETE DATA
   * */

 function deleteData(el) {
    Swal.fire({
  position:'top',    
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cencel',
    confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {

        Swal.fire(
            'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
        )}
         if (result.isDismissed) {
            swal.fire("Cancelled!", "Files not deleted!", "warning");
            console.log("Doing Nothing")
        var recordId = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).deleteData(recordId);
      }
    });
  }

  /** 
   * EDIT DATA
   * https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377357/2391195
   * */

  function editData(el){
    var recordId = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML; 
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateForm).getRecordById(recordId);
  }

  /** 
   * POPULATE FORM
   * */

  function populateForm(records){
    document.getElementById('RecId').value = records[0][0];
    document.getElementById('name').value = records[0][1];
    document.getElementById('State').value = records[0][2];
    document.getElementById('date').value = records[0][3];
    document.getElementById('data1').value = records[0][4];
    document.getElementById('data2').value = records[0][5];
    document.getElementById('data3').value = records[0][6];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>Update Record [ID: "+records[0][0]+"]</div>";
  }
  
  /** 
   * RETRIVE DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET FOR State DROPDOWN
   * */ 

  function createStateDropdown() {
      //SUBMIT YOUR DATA RANGE FOR DROPDOWN AS THE PARAMETER
      //Change to your sheet name and data range. 
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(StateDropDown).getDropdownList("State!A1:A4"); 
  }
  
  /**
   * POPULATE State DROPDOWNS
   * Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391195
  * */

  function StateDropDown(values) { 
    var list = document.getElementById('State');   
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = values[i];
      option.text = values[i];
      list.appendChild(option);
    }
  }

    function loading(){
      window.addEventListener("load", functionInit, false);
      window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmitSearch, true);
    }
  </script>
<script>
  $('#datatable').DataTable()
    .columns.adjust()
    .responsive.recalc();

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Test"); 
    });
</script>
  </script>
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

i hope can sol
```